# count the number of products of all possible subarrays where product should be divisible by four or it is odd

Tags: c++, c++11

i tried to count the number of products which are odd or divisible by 4 , generated by all  possible sub-arrays  but  my implementation get O(n^2).... i need in O(n) time . I also tried to get some pattern but cant found it 
here is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define lli long long int
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    lli testcases,x,M=1000000007;
    cin>>testcases;
    for(x=0;x<testcases;x++){
        lli n,i,j,temp,count1=0;
        cin>>n;
        vector<lli>v;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>temp;
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(v[i]%2!=0 || v[i]%4==0){
                ++count1;
            }
            temp=v[i];
            for(j=i+1;j<v.size();j++){
                temp*=v[j];
                if(temp%2!=0 || temp%4==0){
                    ++count1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(v[n-1]%2!=0 || v[n-1]%4==0){
            ++count1;
        }
        cout<<count1<<"\n";
        count1=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: An observation: once a subarray [i,j] is divisible by 4, any larger subarray that contains it is _also_ divisible by 4.

Comment: This reads like a typical puzzle from some online contest site. If your goal is to learn C++, you will not learn anything there. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution requires knowing some kind of a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is, and attempt to code a brute-force approach, your program runs forever, and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking for the number of subarrays whose product is odd (zero factors of two) or a multiple of four (at least two factors of two).
We can also invert this: take the number of subarrays (2**N) and subtract the number of subarrays that have exactly *one* factor of two.

So, first preprocess the array and replace every number with its factors of two (ie 7 becomes 0, 8 becomes 3, etc).
The question is then "how many subarrays sum to exactly one", which has a known solution.

Comment: ["two to the power N"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), or `pow(2,N)` if you prefer that notation.

Comment: `0 % 4 == 0`, but doesn't have 2 or more multiple of 2 ;) And 0 is also a special case to handle.

Comment: @Botje  Original array is 2 5 6 , if the array stands after processing the 2's factors will be: 1 0 0 , so what should be the answer ?

Comment: 6 is also divisible by 2 ... So the preprocessed array would be [1, 0, 1]

Comment: @Botje sir can u please telll me in detail how the preprocessed array would be with some explainatory examples

Comment: I did so in my answer. Simply count the number of times you can divide by 2 before you end up with an odd number. Please do try to solve this problem for yourself instead of begging for the solution, that is not what StackOverflow is about.

Answer (score 0):

this  question is directly linked to ( april long challenge) from codechef. i don't think its a good idea to ask directly here before the closing of contest (3:00 pm , 13/04/2020).
please obey rules and regulations of codechef.  you can check out at this link if you don't believe my words.
https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/SQRDSUB      or directly visit codechef april challenge (squared subsequence).